# SQL Server 2005 find all columns in database for a certain datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to query the system tables to find all the columns in a database that has a certain datatype.

For example if I needed to know the table name and the column where the datatype = `ntext`

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name -- OR a.* 
  FROM syscolumns a INNER JOIN systypes b
    ON a.xtype = b.xtype
   AND b.name = 'ntext' -- OR OTHER DATA TYPE.
```

Comment: this is perfect for what I need to find except that I need to know the table the column was found in.  How can I modify this to include the table name?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way but this worked perfectly for me. `SELECT     a.name, o.name AS TableName, o.type, a.id, o.object_id, o.schema_id
FROM         sys.syscolumns AS a INNER JOIN
                      sys.systypes AS b ON a.xtype = b.xtype AND b.name = 'char' AND a.length = 6 INNER JOIN
                      sys.objects AS o ON a.id = o.object_id
WHERE     (o.type = 'u') AND (o.schema_id = 1)`

Comment: For new comers. @dlackey 's comment may not work for you. That's because of the redudant length constraint. Use this instead: `SELECT a.name, o.name AS TableName, o.type, a.id, o.object_id, o.schema_id, a.length
FROM sys.syscolumns AS a 
INNER JOIN sys.systypes AS b ON a.xtype = b.xtype 
AND b.name = 'YOUR_DATA_TYPE' 
 INNER JOIN
sys.objects AS o ON a.id = o.object_id
WHERE (o.type = 'u') 
AND (o.schema_id = 1)`

Comment: I added `AND a. length = 6` in my post for a reason but just can't remember why :/ Thanks for watching out for newcomers though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT o.name AS 'Table Name', c.name AS 'Column Name' FROM sysobjects AS o
INNER JOIN syscolumns AS c ON o.name = c.object_id
INNER JOIN systypes AS t ON t.xtype = c.xtype
WHERE b.name = ' ntext'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This erros with b.name cannot be found as there is no alias for b

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT so.name, sc.name
  FROM sys.objects so
  JOIN sys.columns sc ON so.object_id = sc.object_id
  JOIN sys.types stp ON sc.user_type_id = stp.user_type_id
                    AND stp.name = 'ntext'
 WHERE so.type = 'U' -- to show only user tables
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered but I wanted to add the table name to the result set and this query does that.

```
SELECT a.name, o.name AS TableName, o.type, a.id, o.object_id, o.schema_id
FROM sys.syscolumns AS a INNER JOIN sys.systypes AS b ON a.xtype = b.xtype 
AND b.name = 'char' 
AND a.length = 6 INNER JOIN
sys.objects AS o ON a.id = o.object_id
WHERE (o.type = 'u') 
AND (o.schema_id = 1)
```